# PHP - Display Yes No on the feature name

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my database:
[image]

Here is the code that I tried:

```
<?php
//---DB Connection---

//---FIND ALL AMBANK RECORD---
$q = "SELECT * 
      FROM mtid 
      WHERE provider = Ambank";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

//---CREATE TABLE---
echo '<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Serial No</th>';
echo '<th>Feat A?(Y/N)</th>';
echo '<th>Feat B?(Y/N)</th>';
echo '<th>Feat C?(Y/N)</th>';
echo '<th>Feat D?(Y/N)</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    //---FIND FEATURE ID---
    $q1 = "SELECT feat_ID
           FROM functionfeatures 
           WHERE sNo = '".$row['sNo']."' && mmID = '".$row['mmID']."' &&
           ttID = '".$row['ttID']."'";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);

    //---[HERE]---
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['sNo'].'</td>';
    ...
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

I want to make a table like below:
[image]

This table is consists of 5 fields, which is serial number, feature A, feature B, feature C, feature D. 
From my database, serial number 11-11-11-11 have feature B, feature C, feature D. Thus, I want to display No on feature A, Yes on the feature B, feature C and feature D in table.

However, I am stuck on how to compare the feature ID and display Yes/No on the feature name.

How should I continue from the [HERE] section?
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Its difficult to follow your question, peovide more detail on your tsbles and what you are trying to achive

Comment: when you say _"If the feature ID found"_ do you mean if that column is not equal to `null` or zero `0` ?

Comment: To do it in a simplistic way, for each $row you get from the first query, you need to first query to see if that item has FeatA. If so, print Yes. Else, print No. Then, query to see it that item has FeatB. If so, print Yes. Else, print No. Do that for each feature. The way you are trying to do it, the features all come up as multiple rows in a single query with no sense of order. It will be more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one query for that:

```
$query = "SELECT
    m.sNo,
    f.feat_name,
    CASE
        WHEN ff.sNo IS NULL THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS yesno
FROM
    mtid m
    JOIN features f
    LEFT JOIN functionfeatures ff ON ff.feat_ID = f.ID AND ff.sNo = m.sNo
WHERE provider = 'Ambank'
ORDER BY
    m.sNo,
    f.feat_name";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$sNo = '';
echo '<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>sNo</td>
        <td>Feat A</td>
        <td>Feat B</td>
        <td>Feat C</td>
        <td>Feat D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if($sNo != $row['sNo']){
                if($sNo != '') echo '</tr><tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['sNo'].'</td>';
                $sNo = $row['sNo'];
            }
            echo '<td>'.$row['yesno'].'</td>';
        }
    echo '</tr>
</table>';
```

Output is:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer, `JOINS` are definitely the way to go. However why
not remove the `CASE` from your query and leave the results to be `null` so that you can simply use `if(!empty('feat_ID'))` when building your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    // set default values
    $array = array(
        "1" => "NO",
        "2" => "NO",
        "3" => "NO",
        "4" => "NO"
    );

    $q1 = "SELECT feat_ID
           FROM functionfeatures 
           WHERE sNo = '".$row['sNo']."' && mmID = '".$row['mmID']."' &&
           ttID = '".$row['ttID']."'";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);

    // if we have a feat_ID match - set its value in the array to YES
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $array[''.$row1['feat_ID'].''] = "YES";
    }

    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['sNo'].'</td>';

    // output the values for each function ID
    foreach ($array as $yesno) {
         echo '<td>'.$yesno.'</td>';   
    }


    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it a bit different. Using `JOINs` as mentioned but also separating the code to separate your front-end from back-end (Read up on [The MVC Pattern](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)):

Your back-end handles the data, obtains the SQL results and builds the array needed for the front-end:

```
<?php
// $dbc is set in your ---DB Connection---

$sql = "SELECT m.sNo, f.feat_name, ff.feat_ID
        FROM mtid m
        JOIN features f
        LEFT JOIN functionfeatures ff ON ff.feat_ID = f.ID AND ff.sNo = m.sNo
        WHERE provider = 'Ambank'
        ORDER BY m.sNo, f.feat_name";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

$yes_no_feats = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $yes_no_feats[$row['sNo']][] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

As you can see the variable `$yes_no_feats` holds the result which is then passed to the front-end so that it can then be parsed with HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Serial No</th>
        <th>Feat A</th>
        <th>Feat B</th>
        <th>Feat C</th>
        <th>Feat D</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($yes_no_feats as $sno => $features) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $sno ?></td>
            <?php foreach ($features as $f) { ?>
                <td><?= (!empty($f['feat_ID'])) ? "Yes" : "No" ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.